# How do I use android room to create Entity which has multi-list or nested list?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using Room to store some data. but the json is slightly complicated. How can I use Room to do this?

This is my json:

```
{
  "pagination" : {
    "total" : 50,
    "limit" : 30,
    "page" : 1
  },
  "list" : [
    {
      "guid" : "123",
      "data" : {
        "light" : 240,
        "snoring" : 5,
        "talking" : [
          {
            "time" : 1556437167,
            "file" : "file/file.file"
          }
        ],
        "turnover" : 14,
        "temp" : "25.5",
        "duration" : 480,
        "hum" : "78.6",
        "sleep" : [
          {
            "stage" : 1,
            "time" : 1556437167
          }
        ],
        "deep" : 180
      },
      "date" : 1556437167
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I use @Relation,@Embedded and stuff to store/convert this json to Room's Entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this.

```
@Entity
data class List(
    val date: Int,
    val guid: String,
    @Embedded val data: Data
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null
}

@Entity
data class Data(
    val deep: Int,
    val duration: Int,
    val hum: String,
    val light: Int,
    val snoring: Int,
    val temp: String,
    val turnover: Int
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null
}
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Data::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("data_id")
            )
    ]
)
data class Talking(
    val `file`: String,
    val time: Int,
    val data_id: Int
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null
}

@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Data::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("data_id")
        )
    ]
)
data class Sleep(
    val stage: Int,
    val time: Int,
    val data_id: Int
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null
}
```

You have a list of objects And these objects are your actual data
that you might need to store using room.

So inside your list you have 3 items "guid", "data", "date"

Except data other two values "guide" and "date can be saved because they are primitive data type. for data you need another class. And for the Talking and Sleep you need other classes.